# How to sync to a specific folder in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, grive

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
I am trying to sync my Google drive using grive2 in a way that only a specific folder is treated as my root folder in Google Drive i.e., only files and folders contained within the specified Google Drive folder are synced.

I am aware of the -p argument but for some reason I am not able to enter the correct path. Please can someone help.

I have tried the following commands.

```
grive -p ./my_directory -a  

grive -p ./"my_directory" -a  

grive -p "Id" -a #where ID is the id of the resource as per Google Drive API
```

Each of these is throwing the same error.

```
exception: /build/grive2-2Hxkkx/grive2-0.5.1/libgrive/src/util/File.cc(128): Throw in function void gr::File::Open(const boost::filesystem::path&, int, int)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<gr::File::Error>
[gr::expt::BacktraceTag*] = #0 0x578d79 grive gr::Exception::Exception()
#1 0x580917 grive gr::File::Error::Error()
#2 0x57fd69 grive gr::File::Open(boost::filesystem::path const&, int, int)
#3 0x57fe82 grive gr::File::OpenForWrite(boost::filesystem::path const&, int)
#4 0x57fb89 grive gr::File::File(boost::filesystem::path const&, int)
#5 0x57f2cc grive gr::Config::Save()
#6 0x50b63d grive Main(int, char**)
#7 0x50c1e9 grive main
#8 0x7f885cad9830 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 __libc_start_main
#9 0x50a4b9 grive _start

2, "No such file or directory"[boost::errinfo_file_name_*] = ./my_directory/.grive
[boost::errinfo_api_function_*] = open
```

I do not know how to specify the path argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by what you mean by "only a specific folder is treated as my root folder in Google Drive i.e., only files and folders contained within the specified Google Drive folder are synced".

Do you want:

a) my_directory = your google drive root, as I read the first part of your sentence or

b) my_directory = a folder named my_directory in google drive, how I read the second part.

This is how I achieve b) (in my case, my_directory is in ~/grive):

```
cd $HOME/grive
grive -s my_directory
```

I only had to use -a the first time btw.

Comment: by 'only a specific folder....' I mean that gdrive ignores all the other folders are higher in hierarchy from that folder and considers folders and files that are children of that specific folder.

I don't think the your suggestion works for me because to use the `-s` argument I would have had to download the entire gdrive first. At least that is what my experience of using that argument has been so far